# How to get parameters from dynamiclink?

Tags: react-native

*I want to get parameters from dynamiclink if it is possible however I couldn't find the solution.*

this is the link : https://test.page.link/xxx

if I put query parameters to https://test.page.link/xxx?p=3

how can I get that "p" ?

if I use this:

```
 dynamicLinks().onLink((url) => {
      window.console.log('url ', url);
    });
```

I am getting deeplink like :  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Comment: are you able to find the answerer for your above question, I do have a similar requirement. looking for an answer.